# JavaScript Countdown Timer goes to NaN

Tags: javascript, timer, nan, countdown

I am trying to write code in javascript that has a timer start at "100" and count down by 1 until it hits 0. For some reason, however, as I soon as I call startTimer(), it briefly displays "100" before switching to "NaN". Any solutions? Here is my code:

```
function startTimer() {
var o = document.getElementById("timer");
o.innerHTML = "100";
timer_2 = setInterval(displayUnixTimer, 1000);
}

function displayUnixTimer() {
time = document.getElementById("timer");
t = document.getElementById("timer").value;
time.innerHTML = parseInt(t)-1;
}
```

Comment: The `innerHTML` content of an element cannot be retrieved through the `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `innerHTML` value you set originally.

> side note you could pass in the element you are working with to not have to look it up each interval.

```js
var timeText = document.getElementById("timer");
timeText.innerHTML = "100";
var ticker = setInterval( displayUnixTimer, 1000, timeText); 

function displayUnixTimer(element){
  var t = element.innerHTML; 
  element.innerHTML = parseInt(t)-1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced .innerHTML with .innerText in your example and it worked:

```
<html>
<body>
<label id="timer"></label>
<script>
function startTimer() {
  var o = document.getElementById("timer");
  o.innerText = "100";
  timer_2 = setInterval(displayUnixTimer, 1000);
}

function displayUnixTimer() {
  time = document.getElementById("timer");
  t = time.innerText;
  time.innerText = parseInt(t)-1;
}
window.onload = function() {startTimer();};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```